# Convert "long text" field to "long text with summary"

Tags: entities

On my site I've many nodes with a "long text field".
Is there a way to change, also programmatically, this field to a "Long text with summary" field?

Comment: look at answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811840/convert-field-text-to-list-text-drupal-7

Comment: It seems very difficult, I think that I'll create a new field and I fill data, with a bulk operations, from the "old" field

Comment: @sergiod, good idea, more stable at least.